# calculate profit in every row in mysql using php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a product table where wholesale price and reseller price is two columns. I have a third column margin which I want to update with the margin in percent using this formula

((Reseller_price-wholesale_price)*100)/Reseller_price.

This works in Excel but not in Mysql it seems. How should it look either directly in MySql or in a php-script

Thanks in advance from a NON programmer

Comment: Looks like you need do a basic sql tutorial first. Excel Functions <> MySql queries

Comment: Are you able to provide the MySQL query that you're using? Any errors that you're getting from executing the query? What've you tried so far?

Comment: Excel syntax does not work in mysql.  refer to https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/arithmetic-functions.html

Answer (score 1):

Use this query:
`SELECT (((reseller_price - wholesale_price) * 100) / reseller_price) AS profit FROM table;`
You'll need to change `table` to your database table name. Contact your database administrator if you're unaware of table names, column names and data types.

This query will display the profit - but only on the condition that the columns `reseller_price` and `wholesale_price` have data types capable of having arithmatic operations performed on them such as int, decimal, short etc.

If you're dealing with databases in the future, it may help to undergo a [MySQL tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/). Good luck!

Comment: Hi! This work perfect to calculate what I want. But how do insert these values in the third column margin. I will read up on MySql but I am a 62 y.o e merchant so I am a slow learner

Thanks in advance